# Incremental inserts using spark/ pass dataframe value to another sparksql query

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to implement incremental inserts using spark. The approach i'm using here is to get the max value on primary key and use it as set point. But, the problem is how can i convert the dataframe and pass it to another query.

```
id=sqlContext.sql("""select max(requestid) as maxr from st""")
```

## pass id to below query

```
query="""select requestid as maxr from st where requestid='{}'""".format(id)
dfjoin = sqlContext.sql(query)
dfjoin.show()
```

I'd like to see value of id and maxr to be same.Doing the above doesn't seem to work and is not returning any value.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `id=sqlContext.sql("""select max(requestid) as maxr from st""").collect()(0).getLong(0)`... This will give the value of Id... in your code id is dataFrame

Comment: id=sqlContext.sql("""select max(requestid) as maxr from st""").collect()[0][0] worked for me. whereas using getLong(0) was giving callable error

Comment: The syntax mentioned is used in scala...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

below worked for me

```
id=sqlContext.sql("""select max(requestid) as maxr from st""").collect()[0][0]
```